# Refiltering through Model Querys in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I was wondering if you could save the output of a query in a views.py file, and then further query the saved output later.  I need to use all of the information in all_games, and then I need a subset of all_games.  It seemed silly to re-query the database since the data has already been fetched.  Below code is the idea I was playing around with:

```
all_games = Game.objects.filter(league=passed_dict['league'], season=passed_dict['current_season'], home_team=passed_dict['divisions'][i].teams[j])

# [Random Code]

passed_dict['value'] = all_games.filter(is_played=True)
```

Comment: @Alasdair woops, mistake in my question

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the queryset in Python using a list comprehension

```
passed_dict['value'] = [game for game in all_games if game.is_played]
```

However, in practice, you probably won't notice any difference in performance if you use the ORM and it does another query.

```
passed_dict['value'] = all_games.filter(is_played=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Querysets are lazy so unless you do something with all_games in your [ Random code] and then you just filter the all_games - you are simply just chaining filters and no database activity here yet.

Only when you access passed_dict['value'] somewhere else. your queryset is evaluated.

If you evaluate the QS in your [random code] and you work with the items, and you are sure that you don't want any other items from database which are not yet in your evaluated QS, just filter it using loop/list comprehension.